# Foreground Service killed and not restarted

Tags: android, android-service

I have developed an app with Android BLE (bluetooth low enbergy)
It is working fine but when Android require more memory, my service is killed.

- I am using a foreground service with a separate process.

  < receiver android:name=".BluetoothLeService$MyReceiver"/>

  < service android:name=".BluetoothLeService"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true"
          android:process=":myservice"/>

I start my service from activity as:

```
 startService(new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class));
```

and in my service:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    SetNotification(0);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

but when my service got killed by OS, it doesn't restart.
I have tried closing all recent app but not getting any solution....

Is there any solution for this? Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

--- Poweramp app isn't never killed --- why?

EDIT:

MainActivity in OnCreate:

```
...
                startService(new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class));
```

In BluetoothLeService:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver); // receiver for bt on and bt off
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    SetNotification(0);
    return START_STICKY;
}

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public void SetNotification(int VerdeRosso){

    if (VerdeRosso == 1) { // connected
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_connesso);
    }else {
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_disconnesso);
    }
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    startForeground(123, mBuilder.build()); // 123 è l'id a caso
}

   @Override
public void onCreate() {


    mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    //broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    scanLeDevice(true);

}
```

--- EDIT 2

```
    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}
....
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return myBinder;
}
```

Comment: do you have some callbacks and broadcast in your service ?

Comment: cant you use a sticky service

Comment: @Fakher i have a receiver into my service for Bluetooth off and Bluetooth on.  war_Hero... why?

Comment: because if the service is not interacting with your application, it may be killed by the OS. try to take a look at the Google sample project that implement an app using BLE https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt/

Comment: If your service is sticky but still doesn't restart perhaps it's crashing? Did you check logs? Sticky services are "quarantined" for a while if they crash, to prevent endless crash loops. Also, what does your setNotification method look like? Do you supply a valid notification? Previous android versions had a loophole where you could make your service foreground without anyone noticing by supplying an invisible notification, but that is rejected in newer versions, effectively never making the service foreground.

Comment: My service, scan and connect a ble device.. In mainactivity there is only a button for start a service...

Comment: You should also always ask yourself if you absolutely need a foreground and/or sticky service. Way too many apps abuse this concept for no reason, especially in conjunction with starting automatically at boot, resulting in memory being wasted. Of course there are valid use cases for it though, but I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Fakher i have only a button in mainactivity for start a service. What's the problem? My service, scan, if device founded , connet and write charateristich. If it disconnect from my phone, continue scan every 3 seconds.

Comment: if you just start your service without binding it to your activity than try to bind it maybe it will not be killed by OS

Comment: @Fakher ok, but i can make a separate processo ?? for optimizing memory

Comment: no no make them at the same processes

Comment: @Fakher but i have 5 bitamp in my main activity and when check the memory usage i have 40mb.  The drawable are in drawable-nodpi. If i make a separate process my app work with 4, 5mb of memory usage. But  not always i have 4,5 mb..  Theme is a solution? I have only this problem

Comment: in your manifest in application tag add this line: android:largeHeap="true" it's not recommended by try it just to make sure

Comment: @Fakher i have tried but doesn't have any effects. I send from my servie a intent for upgrade the drawable when a device is connected. 
You may depend on what the problem ?  After 30 minutes my service stop!! ..and if i try to connect my phone in android studio logcat, doesn't show anything. Can i make a debug or can i see if there are crash? Thank you

Comment: ok at least put some code. put the new code after binding the service from activity

Comment: @Fakher i have edited my question

Comment: firstly you must declare private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); in your service and than return it in your onBind method.

Comment: @Fakher Ok, i have edited my question.. . now?

Comment: did android kill your service ?
how many this service stay running before it killed ?

Comment: in service there's onLowmermory and onTrimMemory methods please override them and tell me if they are called before the app is killed

Comment: There is not a time definite.. but today is stable.. but yesterday, after 30 minutes android killed my service. Can you suggest me how use onTrimMemory(int) ? I need of implement onLowMemroy?? my app work on 5.0+

Comment: @Fakher please can you make me a answer with a implementation of OnTrimMemory on my Service?? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when the service is killed and restart it again by this way:

```
@Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        //Send broadcast to the Activity to kill this service and restart it.
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
            //Send broadcast to the Activity to restart the service
            super.onDestroy();
    }
```

You can make 2 broadcast or only one of these above.

Comment: Thank you.. but when Android kill a service, OnDestroy is not called by default...and i can't restart this... 1. why you don't call OnTrimMemory? 2. I have a Activity with 5 bitamp. How can i optimize memory usage for my ACTIVITY not SERVICE. Thank you

Comment: use threads to handle these bitmaps because it's a high treatment on bitmaps. for onDestroy just replace it by onTaskRemoved. i edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. I need to implement both method onLowMemory and OnTaskRemoved in my ACTIVITY? and in my service only onLowMemory?

Comment: no you just implement these 2 methods in your service and you broadcast this event to your activity like it's indicated in my answer. please read carefully what you must do in my answer (read what i put in the comment bloc in the code of 2 methods)